# The meaning of the equivalence of the Schroedinger and Heisenberg pictures

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

On my way to explore the equivalence between the Heisenberg and the Schroedinger pictures, I cannot see why textbooks quickly deduce this equivalence from the following:

If $\psi$ is the state of the system (now considered to be independent of time) and $A(t)$ an observable (here a one parameter family of self-adjoint operators in our Hibert space), then the expectation of $A(t)$ in the state $\psi$ is deﬁned by $$\langle A(t) \rangle_{\psi}:=\langle \psi,A(t)\psi \rangle.$$
The observable $A(t)$ is supposed to evolute with time with respect of the following operator valued differential equation $$
\frac{d A(t)}{dt}=\frac{1}{i\hbar}[A(t),H(t)]  
$$
For which it can be shown that $$
A(t)=e^{it H/\hbar}A(0)e^{-it H/\hbar}
$$ where $H(t)$ is the total energy observable and which we see that, by the last evolution equation, it will be constant w.r.t. time $H(t)=H(0)\equiv H$.

We may then compute that $$
\langle A(t) \rangle_{\psi}=\langle e^{-it H/\hbar} \psi,A(0)e^{-it H/\hbar}\psi \rangle=\langle \psi(t) ,A(0)\psi(t) \rangle=\langle A(0) \rangle_{\psi(t)}
$$
where $\psi(t)=e^{-it H/\hbar} \psi$ is now the  time-evolved state of the system in the Schroedinger picture.

Now come the crucial point which is that almost all textbooks claim that 'we thus have that the two pictures give rise to the same expectation values'. How is that? $\langle A(t) \rangle_{\psi}$ is the expectation value of the observale $A(t)$ in the state $\psi$ while $\langle A(0) \rangle_{\psi(t)}$ is the expectation of the observable $A(0)$ in the state $\psi(t)$ ! I mean they are conceptually two different expectation values for a priori two different observales in two different states! any clarifications would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hint: what you call $\psi$ is $\psi(0)$ and  $\psi(t)=e^{-itH}\psi(0)$

Comment: hint2: QM measurements are always statistical averages of outcomes given the QM state as defined by the *wavefunction*.

Comment: Since you commented under a few answers that they helped you: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

In Schrodinger picture, the expectation value is with respect to $\psi(t)$, and $A$ is unchanged, hence write
$$
\langle A\rangle_S=\langle \psi U^\dagger|A|U\psi\rangle
$$
this can be written as
$$
\langle A\rangle=\langle \psi |U^\dagger AU|\psi\rangle
$$
and $A(t)=U^\dagger A U$, or
$$
\langle A\rangle_H=\langle \psi|A(t)|\psi \rangle
$$
Both are equivalent

Comment: But the fact that the two quantities are equal does not clearly imply the equivalence ..they are two expectation values for totally different observable in two different states !

Comment: @user536450 Your comment is strange. This answer shows that the expectation values are *mathematically identical*. So yes they're different states and different observables, but it's exactly the same kind of difference you get by rotating a coordinate system in classical physics. In that case, you have different coordinates and different values of e.g. momentum and position, bu the meaning is equivalent.

Comment: @DanielSank  kind of get it now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Expectation values (i.e., all the measurable quantities) remain the same, regardless of which picture is used.

Comment: but they are two expectation values for a priori different observable in a priori different states !

Comment: States and operators are not observable, but physical quantities are. In fact, Heisenberg matrix mechanics and Schrodinger wave mechanics developed as two independent different mathematical theories, describing the same reality.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalence is not so much between the symbols you write on the page, but between the values you will actually measure. Namely, you will obtain identical expectation values at any particular time for any observables in either picture. The Schrodinger picture gives the time dependence to the wavefunction and leaves the operators time independent, but the Heisenberg picture gives time dependence to the operators and uses the initial time wavefunction. In either case, however, the time dependent expectation value is evaluated using all the same “parts:” the wavefunction at the initial time, the unitary time evolution operators, and the operator whose value you want the expectation value of. This yields identical results. There is even a third option called the “interaction picture,” though we don’t need to get into that here.

Comment: Do you mean that the equivalence is in the sens that expectation values of the 'physical' observables at the time t (independently of our point of view of what would carry the time dependence, states of observales) would be the same since theses two quantities are taken to be encoded respectively by $\langle A(t) \rangle_{\psi}$ and $\langle A(0) \rangle_{\psi(t)}$ right ?

Comment: That is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help.